# Can a version of your managed package be changed from Released to Beta?

Tags: managed-package, isv

During our latest release we removed several Visualforce pages and Apex controller from our managed package. As we were removing all references to these pages we did not think 2 releases would be necessary (one for removing the reference, second to remove the component). All the dependencies were either removed or deprecated in this release.

However, now when trying to upgrade our customers we get the following message:

> This app can't be upgraded.
>   Salesforce has blocked this package upgrade because the new package version removes some Apex code that one or more Visualforce pages or global Visualforce components need in order to function. Please contact your partner with this error information. Provide these component names to your partner. Visualforce Pages: List of visualforce pages....

This would all be fine if we could simply deliver a patch to the customer which removes any references to the components that are blocking the upgrade. However - due to known issue with patch orgs (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XamAAE) we are not able to create a patch org either!

I am wondering if anyone has had any luck in working the Salesforce support team to revert a version from status Released to Beta?

This would allow us undelete the Visualforce pages that are causing the fail, create a new version and deliver our upgrades.

As this release has not been installed in any customer org it feels like it should be a plausible approach.

Has anyone else had any luck when dealing with similar issues? Or are there perhaps any other solutions out there that I am not thinking of?

I have logged a case with Salesforce Support and currently waiting on their answers.

Comment: To my knowledge you will need to do two releases. Also it is possible your upgrade is blocked because internally the customers has built metadata that references your global managed package components. For example if the client creates a VF page internally and embeds your namespaces component, a destructive upgrade will not apply successfully. Are you sure it's not specific to one org or all you client orbs?

Comment: My initial thought was that it was an issue with an internal reference - i.e, customer was using one of our global components, but that was unfortunately not the case.

I also think that a two release process would probably solve this issue, but as we cannot produce a patch org due to another error and we cannot bring these deleted components back into our managed package, the only option seems to do a backup of current data, uninstall the package, reinstall and import data into a new build :(